# How to Generate Random Alphanumeric string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I want to generate a password using numbers ,punctuation and alphabets(both lowercase and uppercase).how can i randomly generate this?

Comment: I have to say, though this is a bad example of a question, I disagree with the close votes, it's not difficult to determine what's being asked, it's just the question is lazy.

Comment: @JamesWebster: I agree with you..

Answer (score 5):

Language-agnostic version, for translation into any language you desire:

Simply create a string which contains the legal characters for a password.

Then generate a random number between (depending on your length requirements) eight and fourteen.

*Then* generate that many random numbers between 0 (inclusive) and `len(str)` (exclusive) and use that to index into `str` to get a character.

Something like (pseudo-code):

```
str = "abc...xyzABC...XYZ0...9,.="
len = rnd(7) + 8                     // rnd(n) gives 0 thru n-1
pwd = ""
while len > 0:
    pwd = pwd + str[rnd(len(str))]
    len = len - 1
```

That'll basically give you a password of the desired length, made up from the desired characters.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged iPhone, I did this in objective c.

```
NSString *string = @"";

for (int i = 0; i < (arc4random() % 6) + 6; i++)
{
    UniChar c = (arc4random() % 89) + 33; //Random char between ! and z
    string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1]];
}
NSLog(@"String:%@", string);
```

- I've assumed ascii.
- I've assumed password length between 6 and 12.
- I didn't put much effort into my answer since you didn't put much effort into your question. You should show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

use `arc4random()` for numbers and  use `arc4random_stir()`